# Homomorphisms from higher rank lattices with infinite center to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lattices

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is an irreducible lattice in a semi-simple real Lie group $G$ of higher rank (with infinite center!), is every homomorphism $\Gamma \to \mathbb{Z}$ trivial?

The case where $G$ has finite center follows easily from Margulis Normal subgroup Theorem. The simplest example I can think of where this question is relevant is the lift of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2}))$ to the universal covering of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\times SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Also, any reference where a discussion about lattices in semi-simple real Lie group of higher rank with infinite center would be appreciated. I only know of Ch.9 Sec.6 in Margulis Book, where I couldn't find an answer to this question.

Thank you!

Comment: It's true if $G$ has a noncompact simple factor with Property T. So the remaining case is that when $G$ is a product of $\ge 2$ rank-1 groups without Property T, as in your specific example.

Comment: Assume for simplicity that that the center is virtually cyclic (we can boil down to this case), so one has to prove that $\Gamma\times\mathbf{Z}$ and $\tilde{\Gamma}$ are not virtually isomorphic, where $\tilde{\Gamma}$ denotes the lattice and $\Gamma$ is its projection modulo the center. One approach would be to prove that $\Gamma\times\mathbf{Z}$ and $\tilde{\Gamma}$ are not IME (integrably measure equivalent). A result in this direction (for cocompact lattices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$) is due to [Das-Tessera](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.2667).

Comment: In the case of $\Gamma=SL_2(Z[\sqrt{2}])$, the central extension of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ will be induced by the holomorphic 2-form on $\mathbb{H}^2$. I think this defines a holomorphic Hilbert modular form on $(\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H})/\Gamma$ of weight $(2,0)$, and it should give a non-trivial 2nd cohomology class on this Hilbert modular surface for each factor. So I think that the extension by $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ should be non-trivial, even for any finite-index subgroup. Hence it should lie in the kernel of a homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes \Gamma \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @IanAgol you're using a semidirect product notation for a nontrivial central extension...

Comment: Thanks for the insight @IanAgol and for the references Yves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, every homomorphism $\Gamma \to \mathbb{Z}$ is trivial.

We may assume that $G$ is simply connected, thus it decomposes as a product of simple factors. Let's consider two cases:

1. $G$ has exactly one non-compact simple factor.
2. $G$ has at least two non-compact simple factors.

In case 1 $G$ has property (T), so also does $\Gamma$ and the result follows.
In case 2 the result follows from theorem 0.8 in

Shalom, Yehuda
Rigidity of commensurators and irreducible lattices.
Invent. Math. 141 (2000), no. 1, 1–54.

Formally, the above theorem applies only for $\Gamma<G$ cocompact, but in fact the proof shows that you need 2-integrability of $\Gamma$ in $G$,
which holds by Proposition 7.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3611.pdf), see the preceding discussion for the definition.

---

The above is an edit of an earlier partial answer I gave, based on the answer of Mikael de la Salle.
See Mikael's answer and YCor's comments for further details.

Comment: Some references about square integrability of lattices are listed in Example 6.8 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1318).

Comment: Hi @YCor, you have a mistake in this reference. A non-compact lattice in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ cannot be square integrable, see Lemma 5.4. in  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.5193.pdf.

Comment: Thanks, fortunately it's the only exception and harmless there. Indeed I relied on a Shalom's (Annals 2000) Theorem 3.6-3.7, proving square integrability of lattice in some Lie groups. Theorem 3.6 says "in $\mathrm{SO}(n,1)$ for $n\ge 4$" and Theorem 3.7 says "if $\mathrm{SO}(n,1)$ is replaced with any other rank one simple Lie group". The proof indeed seems to be done for $\mathrm{SO}(n\ge 4,1)$, then $\mathrm{SO}(3,1)$, and $\mathrm{SU}(n\ge 2,1)$, so only $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$ should be excluded. It's hard to believe that such an ambiguous formulation survived in the published version.

Comment: @YCor, almost. I disagree regarding $\text{SO}(3,1)$. The computation by the end of section 3 in Shalom's paper that you mentioned shows that for $\text{SO}(n,1)$ there is a $p$-integrable domain for every $p<n-1$, in particular a non-uniform lattice in $\text{SO}(3,1)$ is $p$-integrable for every $p<2$. While I do not know a proof that such a lattice in not 2-integrable, I find the converse unlikely. As I mentioned above, for $n=2$ such a proof exists. It could be a nice research project to settle this for a general $n$.

Comment: Thanks again, I hoped you would correct me if necessary.

Comment: About your edit: do you mean that the quite intuitive statement "*If $G$ is a LC-group, $N$ a discrete normal subgroup, $\Gamma$ a lattice in $G$ containing $N$. Then $\Gamma$ is square-integrable in $G$ iff $\Gamma$ is square-integrable in $G/N$.*" is not clear (esp. the $\Leftarrow$ direction, which is needed here)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Initially I assumed it is obvious without checking, then I thought again and it didn't seem obvious anymore. I haven't put much thought on it altogether, anyway.

Comment: OK, I guess it can be fixed. Roughly, let $\tilde{G}$ be the group, $G$ modulo its center $Z$, $T$ be the radical of a minimal parabolic (so $T$ is cocompact, and simply connected solvable). Choose a fundamental domain $D$ that makes $\Gamma$ square-integrable: write $D=\bigsqcup g_nD_n$ with $D_n$ inside a fixed compact subset and $g_n\in T$. Lift $D_n$ to $\tilde{D}_n$, uniformly bounded, and choose $\tilde{D}=\bigsqcup g_n\tilde{D}_n$ as fundamental domain for $\tilde{\Gamma}$, where $g_n$ was lifting according to the continuous lift $T\to\tilde{G}$. Then it seems to work...

Comment: Thanks Yves and @UriBader, I think this gives me enough info to figure it out by myself. When I have a clean proof of the square integrability, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Yves, this seems plausible. I am leaving this to Sebastian to check the details... @shurtados, please let me know if it doesn't go smoothly.

Comment: @UriBader Here's [an amended version](http://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/FWFM.pdf) of my paper (I completed Example 6.8(2) adding missing restrictions, and a footnote. [I'll arXiv it later but just in case you have a look before— I'll post a clone of this message then] Thanks very much for pointing out the flawed statement!

Comment: To be precise the statement of Proposition 7.1 in [dL-dlS] doesn't apply. But what's really proved there is that if $\Gamma/Z$ is a lattice in a semisimple group and has center $Z$ and $\Gamma/Z$ is square-integrable in $G/Z$, then $\Gamma$ is square-integrable in $G$. The 2nd ingredient is: $Z$ has finite index in $Z(G)$ (i.e., $G/Z$ has finite center), which is automatic but needs a proper reference. The 3rd ingredient is: in $G$ semisimple with no compact factor but not simple, every irreducible lattice is square-integrable. The reference seems to be Chap VIII in Margulis' book, Prop. 1.2.

Comment: @Ycor if all you want is the integrability condition given in the formula before Prop 1.2 in Chap VIII in Margulis' book, there is a much easier argument (by Maucourant) giving a much stronger result (exponential integrability), which holds for every "weakly cocompact lattice", and in particular for any lattice in any Lie group. See Theorem 5.3 in my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.01900.

Comment: Note however that this integrability is much weaker than what Uri means by square-integrability. Not only because Margulis has $L^1$ where you require $L^2$. But mostly because to deduce the integrability of the lattice, you need that the lattice is quasi-isometrically embedded [Lubotzky-Mozes-Raghunathan]. This is what Shalom realized, I think... and why the reference should be Shalom.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle what I needed (for me) is Shalom's theorem 4.1 in his 2000 Inv Math paper, which I understood to require square-integrability. Are you saying that QI-embedded + integrable implies square-integrable? and that this was first observed by Shalom? or is it an ingredient among other specific assumptions?

Comment: @Ycor Sorry, I think I missread part of this comment thread, and I am still a bit lost. I was reacting to the fact that the reference you give for square integrability of lattices is Margulis' book. But I do not see anything like this in Margulis' book.

Comment: ... The inequality says something about the rate of decay of the measure of the complement of balls in $G/\Gamma$. What I was saying is that this (and much more) has a very easy proof. And the fact that, when a lattice is QI-embedded (and only then), this rate of decay can be translated to integrability properties of the lattice was, I think first observed by Shalom.

Comment: ... and last : the inequality in Margulis' book is formally an $L^1$-integrability condition, whereas Shalom needs $L^2$-integrability. Of course, as Shalom writes, the sketch of proof that Margulis provides also proves at the same time the $L^p$-integrability for all $p$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a follow-up of Uri's answer. My goal is just to confirm that (for any $p$) the $L^p$-integrability of lattices in a connected semisimple Lie group $G$ follows from the $L^p$-integrability of lattices in $G/Z(G)$. The non-trivial ingredient that is needed is that the central extension $G\to G/Z(G)$ is represented by a bounded $2$-cocycle. The argument (which I think I learned from Nicolas Monod) is at least in Proposition 7.1 of my paper with Tim de Laat https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3611

The fact that this central extension is represented by a bounded $2$-cocycle follows, for simple Lie groups, from the well-known classical work of Guichardet-Wigner, see also the paper Shtern, A. I. Bounded continuous real 2-cocycles on simply connected simple Lie groups and their applications. Russ. J. Math. Phys. 8 (2001), no. 1, 122–133. 
The case of semisimple Lie groups follows by decomposing into simple parts.

Comment: Actually that at the QI-level the extension $Z\to G\to G/Z$ is trivial (and hence represented by a bounded 2-cocycle) is essentially immediate, using that $Z$ is discrete and that $G/Z$ has a simply connected closed cocompact (solvable) subgroup (this is why I used $T$ in my sketch of argument as a comment to Uri's answer).

Comment: Oh, I had never realized that. (and I had not read the comments...) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Mikael.

Comment: Thanks, Mikael, I should have remembered that you had this figured out. I incorporated this into my answer for the benefit of possible future readers. I hope you don't mind...

Comment: @UriBader Sure, it it better if your answer is complete.